# Sorting by time, but with string contamination

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a set of data like this

[image]

The problem is I want to sort the entire dataset, by dep time (departure time). Though that was the best I could do with standard sort functions. I need it to look like

[image]

The only way I can think of doing this is by reading all the data into an array and then sort into a second array, then dump it back to the sheet.. There has to be a more efficient way to do this, I'm just stumped at the moment. If anyone could give any insight.

As a side note, I do need to keep the 'load on flt #' text in the dep time column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create another column in you table?

The main ideia is create a another column with your date/hour like you need, then sort this column.
Example:  `=IF(LEN(F2)>20;MID(F2;19;5);F2)`.

So, don't change values if it fits in 'mm:ss', else remove "Load on Flt...."

Comment: wow, yeah I guess I was just sleep deprived that makes a lot more sense than what I had in mind.

Comment: You also try to use `=FIND()`